# Ошибка: missing 2 required positional arguments:

Tags: python, telebot

[image: Что выдает бот]

Исходный код

```
from extencions import APIException, Convertor
from config import TOKEN, exchanges
import traceback


bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def start(message: telebot.types.Message):
    text = "Приветствие!"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['values'])
def values(message: telebot.types.Message):
    text = 'Доступные валюты:'
    for i in exchanges.keys():
        text = '\n'.join((text, i))
    bot.reply_to(message, text)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def converter(message: telebot.types.Message):
    values = message.text.split(' ')
    try:
        if len(values) != 3:
            raise APIException('Неверное количество параметров!')

        answer = Convertor.get_price(*values)
    except APIException as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, f"Ошибка в команде:\n{e}")
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_tb(e.__traceback__)
        bot.reply_to(message, f"Неизвестная ошибка:\n{e}")
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, answer)


bot.polling()
```

и само взаимодействие с сайтом по обмену валюты

```
import json
import requests
from config import exchanges


class APIException(Exception):
    pass


class Convertor:
    @staticmethod
    def get_price(base, sym, amount):
        try:
            base_key = exchanges[base.lower()]
        except KeyError:
            raise APIException(f"Валюта {base} не найдена!")

        try:
            sym_key = exchanges[sym.lower()]
        except KeyError:
            raise APIException(f"Валюта {sym} не найдена!")

        if base_key == sym_key:
            raise APIException(f'Невозможно перевести одинаковые валюты {base}!')

        try:
            amount = float(amount)
        except ValueError:
            raise APIException(f'Не удалось обработать количество {amount}!')

        r = requests.get(f" https://cash.rbc.ru/cash/converter.html={base_key}&symbols={sym_key}")
        resp = json.loads(r.content)
        new_price = resp['rates'][sym_key] * amount
        new_price = round(new_price, 3)
        message = f"Цена {amount} {base} в {sym} : {new_price}"
        return message
`
```

Comment: А у вас точно последняя версия скрипта запущена?

Comment: вам что, действительно требуется перевод фразы `missing 2 required positional arguments`?